# Future returns correct data but snapshot shows null

Tags: flutter, future

So I am trying to implement the search feature, as you can see I am using a `FutureBuilder` to do it. When the API called it returns the result as expected but when I try using it inside the Future builder it the data is always null:

```
@override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<SearchModel>>(
      future: getResults(),
      builder: ( BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<SearchModel>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          logger.d(snapshot.hasData);
          return ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title),
                onTap: () {
                  close(context, snapshot.data[index]);
                },
              );
            },
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

Future<List<SearchModel>> getResults() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String language = prefs.getString('language');
    var data;
    List<SearchModel> results = [];

    data  = await http.get(Constants.BASE_URL + "/search/" + language + "/" + query,);
    results = (data.map((model) => SearchModel.fromJson(model)).toList());
    return results;
  }
```

Comment: add `print(snapshot)` before `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {` - what do you see on the logs?

Comment: AsyncSnapshot<List<SearchModel>>(ConnectionState.done, null, NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Response' has no instance method 'map'.
 Receiver: Instance of 'Response'
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => SearchModel))

Comment: I am getting the same error as above: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Response' has no instance method 'map'.
 Receiver: Instance of 'Response'
 Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => SearchModel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your API and it's JSON response, so this this is a best guess what your code *should* look like:

```
Future<List<SearchModel>> getResults() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final language = prefs.getString('language');

    final response = await http.get(Constants.BASE_URL + "/search/" + language + "/" + query);
    final results = ((response.body as List).map((model) => SearchModel.fromJson(model)).toList());

    return results;
}
```

That said, you need to check the `FutureBuilder` for `snapshot.hasError` and you need to check your response for `response.statusCode == 200` (or whatever is appropriate for that call) because there is a lot that can go wrong on an external call and you need your app to not crash under those circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

While Future hasn't be resolved snapshot.data is null, check snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done or snapshot.data != null and return Loading widget in the else (with a Loading widget / Progress indicator or similar) and the feature widget in inside the if.

Comment: You should actually read the question and code, not just answer based on the headline.